# JS / jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a simple notifications system but I'm just learning JS / jQuery (front-end is new for me) and I have problem.
I wrote following code:

```
 (function ($) {

    var notification = function(title, msg, duration) {
        this.element = $('<div class="notification"><h3>' + title + '</h3><div class="notification_body">' + msg + '<br/><i>(для скрытия уведомления кликните здесь два раза)</i></div></div>');
        this.element.dblclick(notification.hide);
        $('#notifications_bar').prepend(this.element.hide().fadeIn(1000));
    }

    notification.hide = function() {
        var $this = this;
        this.element.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $this.element.remove();
        })
    }

    $.extend({
        notify: function(title, msg, duration) {
            return new notification(title, msg, duration);
        }
    });
})
    (jQuery);
```

But there is an error in method `notification.hide`: `this.element` is undefined.
Can you explain me where the error?
Thank you.

Comment: can you share html code too ?

Comment: this "notification.prototype.hide = function() {" is better and memory efficient way then "notification.hide = function() {", Answer to your original problem is below from Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a function which *was* attached to an object directly, the function *forgets* which object it was attached to (and therefore the value of `this` changes). This is because the value of *this* is not resolved until the function is invoked.

Instead, use the same approach you used for your `fadeOut` function (storing a reference to `this`, and using it inside an anonymous function;

```
var $this = this;
this.element.dblclick(function () {
    $this.hide();
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `jQuery.proxy()` or `Function.prototype.bind()` (ES5-complient browsers only) which force a value of `this` on the function, no matter where it is attached to later:

```
this.element.dblclick(jQuery.proxy(notification.hide, this));
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt. Callback function doesn't work, but jQuery.proxy works perfectly.

Comment: @DarkNeo: Glad it helped. Clearly 10:30 is too early for me to be writing code on a Saturday, as you were right about the callback approach not working; I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Matt, can you take a look at my code? I updated the question.

Comment: @DarkNeo: Code reviews like this are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com... if you post it on there, and provide me a link, I'll be happy to add my 2 cents on there as an answer :).

Comment: Of course, here it is: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23653/simple-js-jquery-notification-system